# manage.py flush not working during testing

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pipenv

I am using the tutorial on how to use [Django Rest - React and it has some testing in it too](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/tutorial-api-django-rest-react/). When I test it, error comes as:

`CypressError: cy.exec('npm run dev') timed out after waiting 60000ms`.

Because this error occurred during a 'before all' hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: 'Django REST framework / Rea...'

Below is some part of the package.json,

```
{
  "name": "django-drf-react-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "flush": "pipenv run python ./project/manage.py flush --no-input",
    "e2e": "cypress open --project ./project/frontend/",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development ./project/frontend/src/index.js --output ./project/frontend/static/frontend/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./project/frontend/src/index.js --output ./project/frontend/static/frontend/main.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

I think the issue is in flush part. I use virtualenv and I have tried many combinations like:

1. run python ./project/manage.py flush --no-input
2. virtualenv run python ./project/manage.py flush --no-input
3. python ./project/manage.py flush --no-input

I even tried installing pipenv, but to no use. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with this tutorial, what helped me was to first install pipenv and then explicitly state the path to both it and python:

`"flush": "./project_virtenv/bin/pipenv run ./project_virtenv/bin/python ./project/manage.py flush --no-input",`